# Displaying pages for only signed in users

Tags: php

I have created a membership system and only signed in users can enter comments. But, without signing in, everyone can access every pages by typing the name of the PHP file in the link bar.How can i redirect non-registered users to the homepage?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a session if a user has succesfully logged in:

```
session_start(); // best to put this at the top of the first php file that's called, preferably on every page
// check user credentials
if (!valid credentials) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}

$_SESSION['user'] = 'username';
```

And in the php file where you want to check:

```
session_start(); // best to put this at the top of the first php file that's called, preferably on every page

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You forgot exit ! If you don't use it, the script will go on executing and the code is not protected !

Comment: Though most of those scripts use Cookies because a session doesn't last.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: uhhhm no. Cookies are for storing for example a hash so that users don't have to login with their credentials everytime they visit the website. Or for storing for example the prefered language of the visiting user. But has 'nothing' to do with checking if a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

That's just as easy as an if statement :

```
if(login_check())
{
  // Show the page
}
else
{
  header('Location: adresse');   
  exit();   
}
```

Comment: The question is HOW to check. -1

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you identify logged in users, is it a session? a cookie? You should use those methods to test for the logged in status. If the user is not logged in, you should send a `Location` header to redirect him to the home page.

```
header('Location: index.php'); die();
```

You `die();` afterwards to prevent the rest of the code from running.

*Note: You must send it BEFORE any output is sent, otherwise it won't work.*